# nginx non buffered cache

Tags: caching, nginx, varnish

I have an uwsgi application in production which serves intermittent data over 1-2 seconds.

The buffering is set off in nginx to serve any data as soon as it is available.

Now I wan to cache it in nginx or varnish but it looks like it is not possible f the buffer is off!  pointers on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This couldn't be done in nginx, it is unable to cache streamed content.

Varnish version 4 has streaming options
https://www.varnish-software.com/blog/http-streaming-varnish